# Caffeine crashes on start

Tags: 14.04, python

Caffeine crashes on start:

```
valery@valery-P50-A-K4M:~$ caffeine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 89, in get_socket
    s.connect('/tmp/.X11-unix/X%d' % dno)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/caffeine", line 36, in <module>
ewmh = EWMH()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ewmh.py", line 50, in __init__
self.display = _display or display.Display()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 58, in __init__
self.socket = connect.get_socket(name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 78, in get_socket
return getattr(mod, modname).get_socket(dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 91, in get_socket
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Version:

```
valery@valery-P50-A-K4M:~$ caffeine -V
caffeine 2.8.3
```

My question: is there any way to solve this issue or is there any programs with such functionality?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy python3-xlib`? Does it show as installed or none?